# How to generate XOR checksum for a string using perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to generate checksum for a NEMA(GPS protocol) word using perl.
A sample NEMA word is string of characters as shown below

`$GPGLL,5300.97914,N,00259.98174,E,125926,A*28`

The checksum is calculated by taking XOR of all the characters between `$` and `*`. In this sentence the checksum is the character representation of the hexadecimal value 28.

I tried the following:

```
my $NMEA_word = 'GPGLL,5300.97914,N,00259.98174,E,125926,A';
my $uff = unpack( '%8A*', $NMEA_word );
print "Hexadecimal number: ", uc(sprintf("%x\n", $uff)), "\n";
```

But it doesn't seem to give a correct value. Please suggest what shall be rectified

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
my $uff;
$uff ^= $_ for unpack  'C*', 'GPGLL,5300.97914,N,00259.98174,E,125926,A';
printf "Hexadecimal number: \U%x\n", $uff;
__END__
Hexadecimal number: 28
```

Comment: Sometimes I feel there should be an option to upvote more number of times. You saved my day

Answer (score 3):

More functionally,

```
use List::Util 'reduce';
sub checksum {
    sprintf '%02X', ord reduce { our $a ^ our $b } split //, shift; 
}
print checksum('GPGLL,5300.97914,N,00259.98174,E,125926,A'), "\n";
```

Comment: is `our $a` recommended practice?

Comment: perl's builtin sort uses $a and $b and automatically declares them to avoid used-only-once errors, but reduce isn't able to do that, so you either need to disable the once warning or declare them manually.

Answer (score 1):

The `unpack` facility to generate a checksum *adds* the field values together, whereas you want then XORed.

This program will do what you ask.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $NMEA_word = 'GPGLL,5300.97914,N,00259.98174,E,125926,A';  

printf "Hexadecimal number: %s\n", checksum($NMEA_word);

sub checksum {
  my ($string) = @_;
  my $v = 0;
  $v ^= $_ for unpack 'C*', $string;
  sprintf '%02X', $v;
}
```

**output**

```
Hexadecimal number: 28
```